How to swap my custom created token pair on pancakeswap on their website?
Hey guys I have created a token pair using the the pancakeswap factory contract check the below txn
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xa5169b4db0a8564f0c059aab54508526c8a3fad87d5d5682527cdf434d2018ea

Now I want to know how could I add swap this pair on the uniswap website, I have added Liquidity also to the pair on the same contract call as you could see from the txn receipt.
still in the website it says "Insufficient liquidity for trade" when I try to swap the two

Any help appreciated, Thanks in advance guys

To swap your custom token pair on PancakeSwap, try the following:
Check the Liquidity Pool:
Double-check that the liquidity for your token pair is added correctly. You can verify this on PancakeSwap or BscScan by looking at the transaction details. Without sufficient liquidity, swaps won’t work.
Adjust Slippage Tolerance:
If you’re getting errors, increase the slippage tolerance in the settings (5%-10% usually works for low-liquidity pairs).
Approve the Tokens:
Before swapping, make sure to approve both tokens on PancakeSwap so the platform can access them.
Select the Correct Version:
PancakeSwap has multiple versions (V1, V2, etc.). Make sure you’re using the same version where you added the liquidity. You can switch versions in the PancakeSwap interface.
Execute the Swap:
Enter the amount you want to swap, confirm the details, and approve the transaction in your wallet.

Already did that as you could see from the provided resources, my assumption is that maybe the liquidity added is too low for swapping. Can you check that if possible

It seems that your liquidity pool may have an imbalance between WBNB and SERL, or the reserves might be too low for larger swaps.you can try adding more liquidity to the pool, specifically to WBNB, to balance it with the amount of SERL in the pool. Additionally, if you haven't already, increasing your slippage tolerance to 5%-10% might help in cases of low liquidity. Lastly, if the trade size is too large, reducing the amount you are trying to swap could also resolve the issue.let me know if it helps!

To swap your custom-created token pair on PancakeSwap:
Go to PancakeSwap
Connect your wallet (e.g., MetaMask or Trust Wallet)
Navigate to the "Swap" section
Add your custom token addresses in the "From" and "To" fields. You may need to import the token using its contract address
Enter the amount, adjust slippage tolerance if necessary, and confirm the swap
Approve the transaction in your wallet
Ensure your token pair has sufficient liquidity in the pool for smooth swapping

Already did those as you can see from the receipt
